# icon inside button not centered in iphone

Tags: css, iphone, icons, centering

I am trying to center icon inside button so that its centered in every kind of browser. 
I have the following html:

```
<button class="bordered">   
    <i class="icon theme-settings-i"></i>
</button>
```

styled with the following css:

```
button {
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            outline-color: transparent;
            border-color: grey;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 0.2em;
            text-align: center;

            .icon {
                font-size: 16px;
                position: relative;
                color: black;
                top: 0.1em;
                display: inline-block;
            }
}
```

And its centered in desktop chrome, FF and in mobile chrome, Opera. I want to somehow center it horizontally inside iphone's safari. It either goes to the right or to the left no matter what i try.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [this trick](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) to center it horizontally and vertically. (Last example on the page)

```css
button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    outline-color: transparent;
    border-color: grey;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
      }
        
.icon {
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
      }
```

```html
<button>   
    <i class="icon">a</i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not adding line breaks and see the result: for example.
`<button class="bordered"><i class="icon theme-settings-i"></i></button>`